# Excel add column that rounds the number to nearest 500

Tags: excel

I have a list of numbers which goes near 3 million, based on each 500 increment relates to a folder. i.e. 1-500 folder 500, 501 - 1000 folder 1000. I want an additional column (folder) with a folder name.

Example:
34523 has a folder of 35000

[image: Example picture]

Comment: `=CEILING(A1,500)`

Comment: @JvdV that worked perfectly. Wow I did 25k record manually the other day and this has saved me so much time. thank you so much for this.

Comment: You done 25k records manually? Oh my. =)

Answer (score 0):

Simple use Ceiling Function.

```
=CEILING(YOUR_CELL, 500)
```